# JUNTAR INSTRUCCIONES EN TRIGGER

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

En este caso quiero que mi trigger coloque los datos antiguos y nuevos en otra tabla cuando se realice un update , pero no se como hacer para que toda la información me la coloque en una sola fila, ya que en este caso lo he logrado hacer pero de forma incorrecta ya que me coloca la información pero en dos filas ya que para este caso use dos dos select : **select *from inserted** 
para los datos nuevos  y **select * from deleted** para los antiguos ¿Cómo podría hacerlo en una sola fila?
Esta es la instruccion del trigger:

```
create trigger TR_PRODUCTOS_BE on PRODUCTOS for UPDATE
as 
BEGIN 
insert into PRODUCTOS_ACTUALIZADOS (ANTERIORCOD,ANTERIORSEC, ANTERIORNOM,ANTERIORPRECIO,ANTERIORIMPORTADO) 
select CODIGOARTICULO,SECCION,NOMBREARTICULO,PRECIO, IMPORTADO FROM DELETED 
INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS_ACTUALIZADOS (NUEVOCOD,NUEVASEC,NUEVONOM,NUEVOPRECIO, NUEVOIMPORTADO, MODIFICACION, USUARIO1) 
SELECT  CODIGOARTICULO,SECCION,NOMBREARTICULO,PRECIO, IMPORTADO, GETDATE(), SYSTEM_USER fromm inserted
END 
GO
```

El resultado al momento de actualizar los datos me lo muestra de esta forma, como ven me realiza el trigger pero en dos filas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te presento una opción que es bastante simple para hacerlo.

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTOS (CODIGOARTICULO INT
                     , SECCION INT
                     , NOMBREARTICULO VARCHAR(10)
                     , PRECIO FLOAT
                     , IMPORTADO BIT
                     )
GO

CREATE TABLE PRODUCTOS_ACTUALIZADOS (
                       ANTERIORCOD INT
                     , NUEVOCOD INT
                     , ANTERIORSEC INT
                     , NUEVASEC INT
                     , ANTERIORNOM VARCHAR(10)
                     , NUEVONOM VARCHAR(10)
                     , ANTERIORPRECIO FLOAT
                     , NUEVOPRECIO FLOAT
                     , ANTERIORIMPORTADO BIT
                     , NUEVOIMPORTADO BIT
                     , MODIFICACION DATETIME
                     , USUARIO1 NVARCHAR(128)
                     );
GO

CREATE TRIGGER TR_PRODUCTOS_BE on PRODUCTOS
FOR UPDATE
as
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS_ACTUALIZADOS(ANTERIORCOD
                                         , NUEVOCOD
                                         , ANTERIORSEC
                                         , NUEVASEC
                                         , ANTERIORNOM
                                         , NUEVONOM
                                         , ANTERIORPRECIO
                                         , NUEVOPRECIO
                                         , ANTERIORIMPORTADO
                                         , NUEVOIMPORTADO
                                         , MODIFICACION
                                         , USUARIO1)
        SELECT D.CODIGOARTICULO
             , I.CODIGOARTICULO
             , D.SECCION
             , I.SECCION
             , D.NOMBREARTICULO
             , I.NOMBREARTICULO
             , D.PRECIO
             , I.PRECIO
             , D.IMPORTADO
             , I.IMPORTADO
             , GETDATE()
             , SYSTEM_USER
               FROM DELETED AS d
                         full join Inserted AS i on d.CODIGOARTICULO = i.CODIGOARTICULO;
    END; 
GO
```

Si utilizas las dos pseudo tablas y las enlazas con un full join, te presentará siempre 1 linea, a excepción de cuando cambies el código que deleted tendrá lo viejo y inserted el nuevo, y por tanto el enlace no se cumple y te lo presentará en dos lineas.

```
UPDATE PRODUCTOS SET PRECIO  = 11 WHERE CODIGOARTICULO = 1;

UPDATE PRODUCTOS SET CODIGOARTICULO = 3 WHERE CODIGOARTICULO = 1

SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS_ACTUALIZADOS
```

La primera update se va a una linea, pero la segunda que rompe la unión, se va a dos lineas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo he resuelto de otra manera sin join:select D.CODIGOARTICULO,D.SECCION,D.NOMBREARTICULO,D.PRECIO,D.IMPORTADO,I.CODIGOARTICULO,I.SECCION,I.NOMBREARTICULO,I.PRECIO,I.IMPORTADO,GETDATE(),SYSTEM_USER FROM DELETED AS D, inserted AS  i END 
GO   Si lo hago sin el  join habría problemas en este trigger a futuro ? Lo digo por tu comentario al final ya que mencionas que no habría datos actualizados, en este caso con la solución que te menciono de hacer el from al inserted as i, deleted as no habría ese problema de los datos a futuro verdad? Pregunto, gracias por tu aporte del join

Comment: Me extraña que esa solución funcione, porque no mencionar el join, implica que el motor a priori hace un cross join y por tanto hacerte siempre dos filas. Además deberías de probar a realizar la update con varias filas, porque es posible, que el orden no sea el que esperas. Pero si ya lo has verificado, es una forma como otra cualquiera de resolver una relación.

Comment: Sí me funciona y he actualizado varias filas y hace justamente lo que te comento me sorprende a mi también porque no suena algo lógico pero funciona sin hacerme dos filas y me actualiza varios campos sin ningún tipo de inconveniente, lastimosamente no puedo mostrarte el resultado, sin embargo tu ayuda me dio idea para llegar a la respuesta, gran aporte

Answer (score 0):

Tal cual como mencione en el comentario, me funciona con varias filas actualizadas, sin generar dos filas nuevas innecesarias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]